# Sharing permissions and umask not applied to files created within shared folder

Tags: network, permission, sharing, smb, acl

I have a Brother printer which is able to save scans to a Samba v1 share. I have configured a shared only user named "brother" in macOS (Ventura latest release) and have setup everything in the web interface of the printer. The self test of the printer can access the share. A final scan reveals the file on the share. However, the file created by the printer only gets u+rw permissions:

```
sven@Svens-Mac-mini Drucker % ls -l
total 2048
-rw-------  1 brother      wheel  999836 Feb 23 21:28 20230223_212738_MFC-J5730DW_001247.pdf
drwxr-xr-x  2 sven  wheel      64 Feb 23 21:31 test
sven@Svens-Mac-mini Drucker %
```

This is strange as the umask is set to 022 and it properly works when creating a file (test) from macOS Finder directly on the share.

I have checked the ACLs (but I am not an expert either):

```
drwxrwx---+ 5 sven  wheel  160 Feb 23 21:31 Drucker
 0: user:sven allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
 1: user:brother allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxrwx@ 2 sven  wheel   64 Feb 14 15:39 SC Info
sven@Svens-Mac-mini Shared %
```

So, I have no idea what is wrong.

How do I have to set the ACLs to FORCE every file to get a 755 or even 777 permission? If this is not possible: is there a way to trigger a hook script after each change on that specific folder?

Thanks,
Sven